# LLVM: SSA to invoke a function with dynamic number + type of arguments

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, calling-convention, abi

In LLVM and C, one can *extract* arguments from a `va_list` *inside* the called function, without knowing their number and type until runtime.

Like this, in pseudocode (let me know if this is too far removed from SSA; trying to keep it clear/short/high-level):

```
fn callee(...) {
    args = va_list()
    va_start(args)

    // extract the args and use them:
    while not finished {
        switch (expected_type_of_arg()) {
            case "int" {
                int arg = va_arg(args, int)
            }
            case "float" {
                float arg = va_arg(args, float)
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to do the mirror image: *insert* arguments into a `va_list` from *outside* the called function (i.e. at the call site), without knowing the number and type of arguments until runtime. (Assume, though, that I have enough metadata available to match the callee signature, whatever it may be).

Like this (again pseudocode):

```
fn caller() {
    args = va_list()
    va_start(args, alloca(space_needed()))  // e.g.

    // insert the args for the callee:
    while not finished {
        switch (expected_type_of_arg()) {
            case "int" {
                va_assign(args, int, int_val)
            }
            case "float" {
                va_assign(args, float, float_val)
            }
            ...
        }
    }

    invoke(callee, va_list);
}
```

**Is it possible to dynamically construct a function call instruction this way in LLVM?** Assume that it's not acceptable/possible to re-define the callee's signature to accept a pointer to a va_arg (though I'm not sure that would help either?).

As far as I can tell, the `call` SSA instruction requires a compile-time sequence of arguments and a compile-time type signature. Is there a flag, syntax, or different instruction to get around this, and do what is sketched above?

Comment: There's no single instruction or syntax. It is possible for a frontend to generate code, of course.

Comment: @arnt I assume you mean by building a data structure and passing it?

Would that interfere with tail-call (and other) optimizations?

Comment: It depends on precisely what code you generate. But of course, so would a hypothetical instruction.